# mysql_real_escape_string not working on different servers

Tags: php, mysql, function

I have this strange problem.

I have this script:

```
echo $comment_content = $_POST['comment_content'];
echo $comment_content = mysql_real_escape_string($comment_content);
```

When I run it on my website server, it outputs the value only 1 time (not the second one), but when I run it anywhere else, it outputs right (2 times).
However, I use function `mysql_real_escape_string` many times (on the same site) and it never happened before.

This is the whole code, nothing more.

Anyone ever had the same problem? If yes, how did you fix it?

edit: the `<?php ?>` tags also there ofc.

Comment: You shouldn't be using mysql_real_escape_string. To send user input to a database, you should be using bound parameters. If you're not sending it to a database but, say, embedding it in HTML you should use an appropriate technique for that.

Comment: What kind of techniques for example?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`mysql_real_escape_string` needs an existing MySQL connection.
No connection, no escaping.

Comment: Thanks! It was it. But on the other hand, how come that on the other server I was testing it on, it worked even without it? :-)

Comment: +1 because this was driving me nuts! I would give you +100 if I could. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check your queries and connections. If I recall correctly, if there is a problem with the preceding query or connection it causes `mysql_real_escape_string` to fail also. I hit that snag when I first started with PHP + MySQL.

Comment: So what exactly should I look for? :/

Comment: True, it needs valid connection data to work. However, normally you'd see at least one big fat warning if PHP was unable to connect to the server.